# Confused - can't access wordpress dashboard or site that has been published

Tags: login, html

I am a 2/10 wordpress user, so apologies in advance. My dilemma:

- I have a wordpress site linked to my domain, and I access the dashboard through the CPanel from the hosting site.
- I have had a landing page on the website for a while whilst the main site was developed - this shows fine at the domain
- Over a few months, I've developed the main website. Clicked 'publish' this morning. Noticed the website didn't update.
- Went into 'Settings' -> 'General' -> changed SITE URL to the actual website domain (it was showing as www.domain.com/wp, so I removed the '/wp').
- When I clicked 'save', it logged me out, back to the Wordpress login screen. My username and password (autocompletes on this computer, so not manually entered) was incorrect.
- Started getting a '401 unauthorised' screen when clicking on reset password link
- One hour later, I received a reset password email and clicked the link to see a '401 unauthorised' screen
- One hour later, clicking on the reset password link sent me to the new password screen
- Logged in using the new temporary password, to a blank dashboard with only the landing screen and theme on it
- Now, using the username and new password on the login screen, it tells me the password is incorrect
- If I go through my CPanel, I can log in to the same 'old' dashboard with just the landing page on it
- On the top right of the dashboard where I developed the 'new' main site (that I can't access), it said 'Howdy, USERNAME'. The dashboard I CAN access says 'Howdy, Admin' with USERNAME underneath it.
- If I go to www.domain.com/wp, I can see a html only version of the new website I created. If I go to www.domain.com, I can see the original landing page.

It is as if I have two wordpresses, but the only way I access it is through CPanel, so I am unsure what has occurred. The 'denominator' before the access problem was changing the SITE URL, so perhaps this is a clue.

Have you any ideas?

Best,
Gags Galactica

Comment: Yes, changing the SITE URL was probably wrong: you can't just change this to change the URL without also moving the WordPress files or maybe changing configuration in CPanel to change the root folder of the website to be /wp too (if that's actually possible - I don't know CPanel). The simplest thing to do to get your site working again would be to put SITE_URL back: do you have access to the database? If so, you'll find SITE_URL in one of the first two rows in the wp_options table and you can change it back there. (It's also possible to do in wp-config.)

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, perhaps you take a look [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-functions-php) *using `update_option`*